# How to delete items from Recycler View from another class?

Tags: android, position, adapter

I have a Recycler View inside Bottom Sheet , and if the item is clicked, it will be shown in Fragment.

Inside my Fragment i have a delete button (to delete item). How to call `list.remove(position);`?

Delete Button method :

```
buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (view == buttonDelete){
                    switchCardAdapter.deleteMethod(1);
                }
            }
        });
```

> 1 only dummy position , how do i get a real position from adapter?

Delete Method inside Adapter :

```
public void deleteMethod(int position) {
        cards.remove(position);
    }
```

Full BindViewHolder method :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int 
position) {
       final Card card = cards.get(position); 
       holder.textNumber.setText(String.valueOf(card.getNumberCard()));
       holder.textName.setText(card.getName());
       holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("name", card.getName());
                b.putString("description", card.getDescripton());
                b.putString("type", card.getType());
                b.putLong("numberCard", card.getNumberCard());
                b.putInt("cvv",card.getCvv());
                b.putInt("exp", card.getExp());
                b.putInt("pin", card.getPin());
                cardFragment.setDataCard(b);
                bottomSheetFragment.dismiss();
        }
    });
}

public void deleteMethod(int position) {
    cards.remove(position);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: delete the item from list then notify to Adapter it will remove automatically from recyclerview list

Comment: check the latest questions

Comment: what problem you are facing now?

Comment: how to delete items from another activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void deleteMethod(int position) {
        cards.remove(position);
        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)
    }
```

As per my understanding, your code flow should be like below:

From one fragment you have open 1 bottom sheet that contains RV items. now when user clicks on RV item, You have open New fragment from "Card fragment" and dismissed bottom sheet. In new fragment you have passed bundle data. In card Fragment , you have delete button that will remove item from list of cards.

So From your card fragment using interface, you have to notify to your first fragment from where you have open Bottom sheet. In this fragment you have to remove that particular item from list for cards. ( you have to pass position from card fragment to first fragment to delete from list ).

Now your card list is updated. You can again open Bottom sheet with newly updated list. ( previously in onbindViewHolder, you have dismissed) .

Comment: check the latest questions

Comment: Please correct if wrong.
From one fragment you are trying to open Bttomsheet that contain recyclerview items.

now when user click on any item in bottom sheet, you are opening card fragment  and passing bundle items. In cardFragment you have delete button and click on that delete button, you want to remove the item from list.

Comment: So, You can pass position as well in a bundle. 
Now let me know how you have open card fragment means from where?

inside onBindViewHolder you are doing 
cardFragment.setDataCard(b);
                bottomSheetFragment.dismiss();

Comment: is that require ```cards.remove(position)``` ? , because the remove method has a null object reference

Comment: check the updated answer, let me know if that suits your requirement

Comment: ```java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.remove(int)' on a null object reference
        at me.muhammadfaisal.mycarta.home.fragment.card.bottom_sheet.switcher.adapter.SwitchCardAdapter.deleteMethod```

Comment: Line 79 ```cards.remove(position);```

Comment: I don't have any code. I am just letting know the flow. If possible, share your code link, I will check and update you

Comment: do u have telegram?

Comment: check your telegram

Comment: t.me/kishankrmaurya

Answer (score 0):

Your `adapter` should be notified when changes happen to it's data source as in

```
public void deleteMethod(int position) {
    cards.remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

or more efficient

```
public void deleteMethod(int position) {
        cards.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        //enables smooth animations and also updates data
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount());
}
```

When click on item, pass position in bundle and use it in cardfragment to delete it

```
            b.putInt("position", position);//add this
            cardFragment.setDataCard(b);
            bottomSheetFragment.dismiss();
```

then, deleteButton onclick,

```
buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (view == buttonDelete){
                    switchCardAdapter.deleteMethod(bundle.getInt("position));
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: `notifyItemRemoved` is the better option

Comment: @npk right. bcz it will show animation as well. When the item will be removed

Comment: check the latest questions

Comment: ```Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.remove(int)' on a null object reference
        at me.muhammadfaisal.mycarta.home.fragment.card.bottom_sheet.switcher.adapter.SwitchCardAdapter.deleteMethod(SwitchCardAdapter.java:80)``` and line 80 : ```cards.remove(position);```

Answer (score 0):

To delete from list

```js
cards.remove(position);
```

Notify adapter to remove:

```js
adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)
```